# Using Max() In Join

Tags: mysql, max, left-join

This is a type of query that I need.  But I keep getting an error because of using the MAX() function in the join.  How can I write a valid query with this logic?

EDIT: I've updated my query and it is not returning an error.  However, there is a logical error with this.  If image.sort_index = -1, I do NOT want the max sort index.  How do I break the boolean condition check if image.sort_index = -1?  Below is the updated query

```
SELECT 
    albums.ID, albums.title, images.ID AS thumb_id, images.image_count as image_count
FROM
    `albums` 
LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT
        ID, album_id, sort_index, 
        MAX(sort_index) AS max_sort_index,
        COUNT(ID) as image_count
     FROM
        `images`
     GROUP BY album_id
     ) 

     ON images.album_id = albums.ID 
     AND 
     (images.sort_index = -1 OR images.sort_index = images.max_sort_index)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What error do you get? I'm not seeing anything that MySQL woudldn't permit (though others would def complain, and you wouldn't get the expected result anyway).  What result set do you want? Please post a sample of input rows and a sample of the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The `MAX()` function is an aggregate: it only is run after all the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses are executed.  Instead, break it out as a subquery, so it is run once, and run before the rest of your outer query:

```
SELECT 
    albums.*, images.ID as album_thumb 
FROM 
    `albums` 
LEFT JOIN `images` ON 
    images.album_id = albums.ID
    AND

    (images.sort_index = -1 OR images.sort_index = (
            SELECT MAX(sort_index) FROM images
        )
    )
```

The downside is that if you want any additional restrictions (`WHERE` clauses) on your outer query in the range of `images`, you would need to duplicate them in the subquery as well.  This is a limitation of SQL.

Comment: Can you check out the updated query and give your opinion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN `images` ON 
images.album_id = albums.ID
AND (images.sort_index = -1 OR images.sort_index = (SELECT MAX(images.sort_index) FROM images))
```

MAX is an aggregate function, and in this case, needs to be placed in a sub-query to get the results you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    albums.*, images.ID as album_thumb 
FROM 
    `albums` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `images` ON images.album_id = albums.ID
WHERE
    images.sort_index = -1 OR images.sort_index = (select MAX(tmp.sort_index) from images tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally have a solution, which I'm posting in case someone else runs into the same issue.  Additional fields are included in this answer to show the broad scope of this solution.

```
SELECT albums.*,  tbl2.ID as thumb_id
FROM albums
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT album_id,MIN(sort_index) min_sort, MAX(sort_index) as max_sort FROM images
    GROUP BY album_id
) tbl ON tbl.album_id = albums.ID
LEFT JOIN images tbl2 ON tbl2.album_id = albums.ID AND 
(tbl.min_sort = -1 AND tbl2.sort_index = -1) OR 
(tbl.min_sort > -1 AND tbl2.sort_index = tbl.max_sort)
```